# Detect if Redis connection before connecting

Tags: asp.net, caching, redis

I've implemented a Redis server (to be used as a data cache) for a web application (ASP.NET).

One of the design goal is to allow the web application to function normally if the Redis server goes down.

Currently this does work, however it is **very very slow**.

below is a code chunk from the Class that deals with Redis:

```
public string GetCachedData(string k)
    {
        string res = string.Empty;


        if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.GetValues("UseMemcache")[0].ToString() == "False")
        {
            return res;
        }

        try
        {
            using (RedisClient rs = new RedisClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.GetValues("RedisServerIP")[0].ToString()))
            {
                byte[] buf = rs.Get(k);

                if (buf != null)
                {
                        res = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetString(buf);
                }   
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            res = "";
        }

        return res;
    }
```

**Question:**

On the line

```
(RedisClient rs = new RedisClient)
```

This is where the application will block for long time before throwing an exception.

How can this be done such that it throws immediately?

Comment: Does Redis offer this type of fuctionality now? It has been nearly four years.

Answer (score 1):

You can't detect network timeouts instantly, but you can minimize the impact. The problem is that you try the connection and get the timeout on every request. Try this version - if there is an error it will stop trying to use the cache for the next five minutes.

```
public DateTime LastCacheAttempt {get;set;}
private bool? UseMemCache {get;set;}

public string GetCachedData(string k)
{
    string res = string.Empty;

    if (UseMemCache == null) {
        UseMemCache = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.GetValues("UseMemcache")[0].ToString() != "False";
        if (!UseMemCache) LastCacheAttempt == DateTime.MaxValue;
    }

    if (UseMemCache || LastCacheAttempt < DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-5))
    {

    try
    {
        using (RedisClient rs = new RedisClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.GetValues("RedisServerIP")[0].ToString()))
        {
            byte[] buf = rs.Get(k);

            if (buf != null)
            {
                    res = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetString(buf);
            }   
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        UseMemCache = false;
        LastCacheAttempt = DateTime.Now;
    }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: I had already thought of something similar to your solution. I was hoping that the client API had something built in. I guess this is not the case, in which case I'll probably end up following your suggestion.

Comment: I'll wait a little longer to see if any other solutions surface, if not then I'll mark as accepted.

Comment: I'm not aware of any general purpose client libraries that have a full retry/failure strategy built in, probably because it differs too much with usage - that code works for optional caching but would be completely inappropriate if redis is the primary data store.

Comment: In my case, redis only acts as a effective cache (the actual datastore is just a sql server backend) I just wanted to be able to smoothly handle a redis fail-over.